# Matching certain string ending in 1(any digit) but not just 1

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to write a regex in Python to match strings such as `rds2`, `rds5`, `rds11`, but not match the string `rds1` or any non `rds`-followed-by-digits string, e.g. `camels2`.

My current regex is just

```
^rds[^1]
```

however this doesn't match strings which end in 1 followed by another digit. I am not very familiar with regex, but I think I have to use a look-behind assertion to make sure that at the end of the string, if the last character is `1` then the previous character was `[0-9]`?

I attempted to do so, but have ended up in a mess where the look-behind assertion length seems variable on how many digits the string ends with.

Comment: `^rds([02-9]|[0-9]{2,})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead:

```
^rds(?!1$)\d+$
```